# Shorted power to ground through resistor (Raspberry Pi Pico)

Tags: pi-pico

I have a similar question to this post:
[Shorted Raspberry Pi Pico 3v3 pin to GND](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/137905/shorted-raspberry-pi-pico-3v3-pin-to-gnd)

I have shorted pin 36 to 38 through a 1.5k resistor.

I assume that because of the resistor there should have been absolutely no chance at damage, as the current draw could not get large?

Would this be correct?

Comment: If works: no damage else: damage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohms law say **V = I x R**

Transform it to **I = V / R**

And if you apply this to your scenario :

```
V = 3,3 volt
R = 1,5k ohm
= I = 2,2 mA
```

And as @Milliways corrected me. 2,2 mA is way under the power regulator  Max 300 mA.

And if you had shortened a GPIO to ground it is within the max current.

The RP2040 datasheet state in the datasheet that "Output drive strength can be set to 2mA, 4mA, 8mA or 12mA.". Default is set to 4 mA.

And the max 50 mA, sum of all current being sourced/sunk by GPIO and QSPI pins.

https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/rp2040/rp2040-datasheet.pdf

Comment: The OP has connected a load across the 3.3V power pin - which can source 300mA.

Comment: Thx @Milliways for pointing it out. I should have checked the pins!

Answer (score 1):

That's correct - no chance for damage under the conditions you've stated. Technically, you have not ***"shorted"*** anything at all. See the [definition of a "short circuit" here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_circuit)